# Sending multiple emits inside a loop

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

We currently need to send data to multiple connected client, each of them have a unique channel name, for instance CHANNEL1, CHANNEL2, CHANNEL3 Etc. When trying to cycle through all the channels for example, 30.000 channels. It sends the first one, then it waits till the loop finishes before sending the rest.

```
io.on('connection', function (socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function (msg){      
      for (i = 0; i < 30000; i++) {
        io.emit('CHANNEL' + i, msg);
      }
  });
});
```

Is there a way it sends the emits asynchronously, while it loops 1 by 1?

Answer (score 1):

The io.emit call is async.  You should ideally call it and wait using a callback before calling it again.

The best approach would be to use the async library (https://github.com/caolan/async/, `npm install asnyc`, and using the `each()` method.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer, i Tried this solution but it still is waiting to finish the loop before emitting all the data. Not sure if there is a socket.io configuration that has to be set to enable multiple parallel emits.

Comment: @FranzSilva87 I have the same problem, but into a recursive function. I'm getting all events at the end of the recursion. Did you figure out why?

Comment: The same appears in socket-io-cpp client. I have tried with std::async but not lack. All emits are submitted in the end. :(